# difference between icu4c opentype harfbuzz

Tags: icu, opentype, harfbuzz

These three open source library are used in android very frequently. I just know that these library are used to handle fonts. 
I was thinking what is the difference between in these library and Are they interrelated with each? or They can substitute one another.

Answer (score 12):

[OpenType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) is not a library, it is a standard for “smart” font that is the most widely used format for advanced typography and support for complex writing systems.

[ICU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode) is a library for Unicode support, it provides many features like Unicode characters properties, Unicode Bidirectional algorithm implementation, encoding conversions and more. ICU provides also an OpenType implementation, ICU LayoutEngine, but it is not used by Android AFAIK, it is also unmaintained and will be replaced by HarfBuzz at some point.

[HarfBuzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HarfBuzz) is a text shaping library, in short it takes a font, a string of text and some properties (script, language, optional OpenType features) and return a sequence of font glyph ids that a rendering engine will draw them on the screen. It is mainly an OpenType implementation, but can support other font technologies. It is a bit of low level library and requires some understanding of fonts and text rendering to be used properly.